# Use array formulas to concatenate two independent sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation

I have two Google Sheets with identical layouts that are filled in by independent teams:

*Sheet 1:*

```
team1_entry1 243
team1_entry2 546
etc
...
XXX
```

*Sheet 2:*

```
team2_entry1 166
team2_entry2 888
...
XXX
```

I need to see the data from both sheets in one table, which I can then filter and sort using Filter Views. I wrote a simple Apps Script function to go through each sheet and grab all the values until it hits "XXX". The collected data is then written as a two-dimensional array in my sheet. (I use `IMPORTRANGE()` of this data into another sheet, from which I generate my Filter Views, etc.)

#### The problem

This workflow doesn't work offline (Apps Script needs the internet to run), and I would like to be able to work on this data when I don't have internet access.

Would it be possible to do this kind of sheet data concatenation using some kind of array formula wizardry?

---

My currently-working script code, for reference:

```
function CreateMasterTableTest( ) { 
  var name_of_a_sheet                  = 'Team1Sheet';
  var name_of_b_sheet                  = 'Team2Sheet';
  var num_tables                       = 2;
  var database_terminating_string      = 'XXX';
  var start_of_data_row_index          = 1; // 2nd row in the sheet
  var ss                               = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    
  var all_values    = [];
  var a_sheet       = ss.getSheetByName( name_of_a_sheet );
  var range         = a_sheet.getDataRange();
  all_values[ 0 ] = range.getValues();  
  var b_sheet       = ss.getSheetByName( name_of_b_sheet );
  var range         = b_sheet.getDataRange();
  all_values[ 1 ]   = range.getValues();
  var output_array                     = [];
  var global_row_index                 = 0;
  var end_of_data_encountered          = false;
  
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Now I have to reserve space for the second dimension
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  for ( var i = 0; i < ( all_values[ 0 ].length + all_values[ 1 ].length ); i++ ) {    
     output_array[ i ] = output_array[ i ] || []; 
  }
  
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Walk through each row and each column of each sheet
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  var a_num_rows = all_values[ 0 ].length;
  var a_num_cols = all_values[ 0 ][ 0 ].length; // this gets the number of cols   
  for ( var table_index= 0; table_index < num_tables; table_index++ ) {    
   for ( var row = 0; row < a_num_rows; row++ ) {
    for ( var col = 0; col < a_num_cols; col++ ) { 
      temp_val                        = String( all_values[ table_index ][ row ][ col ] ); //#VALUE! 
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // At this point we shall check for the terminating string
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      if ( database_terminating_string == temp_val ) {
          end_of_data_encountered = true;          
          break; 
      }            
      if ( start_of_data_row_index <= row ) {
          output_array[ row - start_of_data_row_index + global_row_index ][ col ] = temp_val; 
      }      
    }    
    if (  end_of_data_encountered == true ) {
      end_of_data_encountered = false;
      global_row_index = row - 1;
      break;
    } //end of if
   } // end of row for loop
  } // end of tables for loop
  return output_array;
}
```

Edit 2:
Here is the sheet formula I have come up with, but I can't get it to work for both sheets:

```
=Indirect( "Sheet1!A3:HA" & Match( "XXX", Sheet1!A3:A1000, 0 ) + 1 )
```

And likewise for Sheet2

```
=Indirect( "Sheet2!A3:HA" & Match( "XXX", Sheet2!A3:A1000, 0 ) + 1 )
```

Below doesn't work for me:

```
=concat( Indirect( "Sheet1!A3:HA" & Match( "XXX", Sheet1!A3:A1000, 0 ) + 1 ), Indirect( "Sheet2!A3:HA" & Match( "XXX", Sheet2!A3:A1000, 0 ) + 1 ) )
```

I need something similar to concat that works for Arrays, perhaps.

Edit3: Seem to have found a solution

Instead of concat above, use {array1;array2} approach.

In other words, in my case it is:

={Indirect( "Sheet1!A3:HA" & Match( "XXX", Sheet1!A3:A1000, 0 ) + 1 ); Indirect( "Sheet2!A3:HA" & Match( "XXX", Sheet2!A3:A1000, 0 ) + 1 ) }

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: @QHarr Just did. Hope it makes it clearer what I want.

Comment: You might try something with `INDEX` and `MATCH` to find the position of your keyword. Note that your question is currently "I can't seem to do this, can it be done?" or "I can't solve this, solve it for me" - both of which I would argue aren't great questions. If you include attempts you've made already to perform such a formula-based concatenation, I think you will get a better reception. Also - when you say "two independent sheets", do you mean same or different workbook?

Comment: @tehhowch The sheets are independent, but I have access to them and bring them into my "master" workbook by using IMPORTRANGE(). I tried Index and Match and it works for one sheet - see Edit2 in my OP - but I don't know how to combine two independent sheets.

Comment: @tehhowch After searching around a little more, I think I have found the solution (see Edit3). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @a1s2d3f4 consider posting your solution as a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) so others can benefit from your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={Indirect( "Sheet1!A3:HA" & Match( "XXX", Sheet1!A3:A1000, 0 ) + 1 ); Indirect( "Sheet2!A3:HA" & Match( "XXX", Sheet2!A3:A1000, 0 ) + 1 ) }
```